# Hide automatically generated OpenAPI documentation

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi-generator

I have created costume APIs in Spring Boot Java 21 and I want to show them in Swagger I have used the following dependencies

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

the result shows me my costume APIs and auto-generated APIs from all my entities, Now I want to **hide auto-generated APIs** or show them in **separate URLs**.

also I tried to use `springdoc.packagestoscan=om.gov.pasi.gccintegration.controller` property but still it dosnt work with me

Answer (score -1):

You can use the @Hidden annotation from the Springdoc library to hide specific controllers or endpoints from the generated API documentation. Annotate the controllers or endpoints that you want to hide with @Hidden. and if you want to show auto-generated APIs in separate URLs, you can define multiple instances of the OpenAPI bean with different configurations. Each instance can include specific controllers or packages and be exposed on different URLs.
Here's an example of how you can customize the OpenAPI configuration to include or exclude specific controllers using a custom OpenAPI bean:

```java
@Configuration
public class OpenAPIConfig {

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI()
                .components(new Components())
                .paths(new Paths())
                .info(new Info().title("Custom API Documentation").version("1.0"));
    }
}
```

if you need any details feel free to ask.